# Criteria and sorting according to it

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Hi I have 2 problems related to hibernate criteria

I have the following product which contain many colors.

I wish to find the product which contain at least RED and GREEN.

```
Product class

    String id;

    name;

    style;

    List<Color> colors{};

Color class

    id

    color
```

1) Every time I do a retrieval, each product will appear depending on how many colors it has..
for example a product A has red green blue, it will appear 3 times.

I have used FetchMode: Select but it doesn't seems to change.

The only possible solution I can think of is inserting them into a hashset and rewrite the hashcode and equal method for primary key only

2) How do I return queries that is sorted according to the closest match to my search?

For example I search for style and color red,green.

so products that matches style color and red green

Comment: You're asking at least two questions here.  It might be better if you separated them.  And please, show us some code that exemplifies the problems you're having.

Comment: @Don Roby I'm afraid this is not a development computer and I can't show you the codes. I will try and draft a mock code when I am home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You use need to distict results.

It is not a matter of changing FetchMode.

Please take a look article [this](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-AdvancedProblems#Hibernate_does_not_return_distinct_results_for_a_query_with_outer_join_fetching_enabled_for_a_collection_even_if_I_use_the_distinct_keyword)

```
setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
```

2) Well... there is no that kind of criteria function to automatically find and order closest match stuff

Anyway, the simplest way to make similar function is to use addOrder with createAlias instead of setFetch

```
ct.createAlias("colors", "cs")
  .add( Restrictions.like("style", value + "%"))
  .add( Restrictions.in("color", colorsArray ))
  .addOrder( Order.asc("style"))
  .addOrder( Order.asc("cs.color"))
```

I cannot write all kind of match method in here.

Please refer Restrictions's various expression on [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples)

Comment: solution 1 works but solution 2 doesn't seems to answer the question, that merely order the style but not by the search.

Comment: yes, that's for sorting. I though you already have your own match criteria waiting for sorting. I will put some match method either.